# How to calculating data/error blocks number of QR code at version > 3

Tags: encoding, block, qr-code

I am working on a QR code encoding/decoding project.

I have been read through the ISO/IEC 18004 (2006) and some tutorials ( http://www.thonky.com/guides/
http://www.matchadesign.com/_blog/Matcha_Design_Blog/post/QR_Code_Demystified_-_Part_1/
http://www.swetake.com/qr/qr1_en.html
)

The ISO documentation and those very nice tutorials helped me a lot. But there’s still one thing I can’t understand, that’s how we can calculate **the number of data/error blocks** when creating a QR code at Version 3 or higher.

The image below is from the ISO/IEC 18004 – 2006:

[image]

A version 7-H (H is error correction capacity level ) symbol that has **66** data codewords and **130** error codewords. They split both of them into **5** blocks.

The document says that the **n blocks** number (in this case **n** = 5 ) can be calculated from Table 9 (ISO 18004) according to the version and error correction level. But it seems like I can’t get that number. Please show me how I can calculate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I got it. All needed information for block splitting actually is at Table 9 of the ISO/IEC 18004 document. Just because of my careless reading.